# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I encounter a problem when I use lm together with loop. I want to fit regression lines with every four values of `xx` and `yy`.

Here is my code,

```
>xx<-c(0 , 55, 146, 457, 643, 825,1008)
>yy<-c(NA, 110, 132, 108, 124, 115, 134)
>n<-length(xx)
>slop<-rep(NA,n)
>for (i in 4:n){
   x<-xx[i-3:i]
   y<-yy[i-3:i]
   slop[i]<-lm(y~x)$coefficients[2]
   }
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Could anyone please tell me why this happen? I try to do it manually, pick every four values of `xx` and `yy` and use `lm`, then R runs successfully.

Comment: I finally find the error and maybe it's helpful for someone who has same confusion. t<-i-3 is needed in loop, or else when i take value larger than 6, then R get confused and stop to do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `[i-3:i]` to `[(i-3):i]` eliminates the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because of operator prioriy (between `-` and `:`) it is not doing what you expect:

For the first iteration you get:

```
4-3:4
[1] 1 0
xx[4-3:4]
[1] 0
yy[4-3:4]
[1] NA
```

And hence:

```
lm(yy[1]~xx[1])
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

To ensure you get what you want, you need to add brackets to explicitly state the order of operators required:

```
(4-3):4
[1] 1 2 3 4

for (i in 4:n){
x<-xx[(i-3):i]
y<-yy[(i-3):i]
slop[i]<-lm(y~x)$coefficients[2]
     }

slop
[1]           NA           NA           NA -0.023502847  0.001080591
[6] -0.018919254  0.037666732
```